# Adding Namespace Artifacts to Visual Studio Layering Diagram

Tags: .net, visual-studio, architecture, uml

**What am I able to do?**

I have created Visual Studio Modeling Project. Inside the project I have a Layering Diagram. Inside the diagram I can create boxes that correspond to layers. Using drag & drop I can include artifacts like assemblies or types into a layer. Then I can define layer dependencies by drawing lines and architecture validation also works fine.

**What am I trying to achieve?**

According to [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409462.aspx) artifacts associated to the layer can be not only assemblies or types, but also namespaces:

> Layer
> A logical group of physical artifacts in your system. These artifacts can be namespaces, projects, classes, methods, and so on.

I want to be able to associate a certain namespace to an artifact so that if a type is added to this namespace it automatically is included into the validation. This behavior is given for assemblies, so it is obvious to expect it for namespaces too.

**What have I tried so far?**

I have not managed do drag & drop a namespace from class explorer into the layer. I did not found any other way to do that. Nevertheless there are namespace related properties on layer itself.

> **Forbidden Namespace Dependencies** - Specifies that artifacts associated with this layer cannot depend on the specified namespaces.
>
> **Forbidden Namespaces** - Specifies that artifacts associated with this layer must not belong to the specified namespaces.
>
> **Required Namespaces** - Specifies that artifacts associated with this layer must belong to one of the specified namespaces.

But this properties just put some restrictions on artifacts belonging to the layer. None of them associate an artifact corresponding to a namespace to the layer.

**Question:**

Is it possible to associate an artifact corresponding to a namespace with a layer inside Visual Studio Modeling Project's Layering diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally by playing around I figured it out myself.

**Answer:** 
Yes you can use namespaces as artifacts. You can read it everywhere and see in some webcast videos e.g. [Using layer diagrams to design and validate your architecture](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-2012-Premium-and-Ultimate-Overview/Visual-Studio-Ultimate-2012-Using-layer-diagrams-to-design-and-validate-your-architecture)

I have not managed to accomplish that from Solution Explorer, Class Explorer or Object Browser. It works only if you first generate a **Code Map** for instance by right clicking a project in Solution Explorer. Then you navigate to the namespace you want and drag & drop a namespace into your layering diagram.

[image: Drag & drop a namespace from the code map into your layering diagram]

Comment: Hi George, in the lower tier you have layers, for example 28 in "Security", multiple artifacts linked. How did you achieve this? I always end up having one element per layer.

Comment: Multiselect Classes + Drag & Drop